# Getting "?" in Project Navigator

Tags: iphone, xcode, xcode4.2

i copied a few ".h" and ".m" files from my old project to my new project.and now i am getting "?" badge instead of "M" or "A".

Does it have anything to do with the proper functioning of the project?

But i can see my project running well.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It just means that your new files aren't under version control, so Xcode can't tell in which state they are (A(dded), M(odified) or D(eleted)). Right click->source control->add should fix it.

Answer (score 2):

No that just means the files are not under version control. You should check them in. It does not affect the function of the project.